Why calling component method array with data becomes empty?
In laravel 11 / livewire 3 app in Dashboard component in $newsGroupedByNewsCategoryList array
I save groupped data which are read from db and show them in blade file. It works ok, but
now I want with any category group to add button,
clicking on it last 5 news of this group woul be shown below ths button. When I click on this button $newsGroupedByNewsCategoryList array is cleared and I do not understand why?
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Admin;

...
use App\Models\News;
use Livewire\Component;

class Dashboard extends Component
{
    public $newsGroupedByNewsCategoryList;
    public string $fetchedNewsCategoryContent = 'default fetchedNewsCategoryContent';
    ...
    public function boot(LoggedUserInterface $loggedUserService)
    {
        $this->loggedUserService = $loggedUserService;
    }


    public function mount()
    {
        $this->retrieveDbData();
    }


    protected function retrieveDbData(): void
    {
        $newsTb = (new News)->getTable();
        $this->newsGroupedByNewsCategoryList = News
            ::getByPublished(NewsPublishedEnum::PUBLISHED)
            ->groupBy('news_category_id')
            ->select($newsTb . '.news_category_id',
                DB::raw('count(' . $newsTb . '.id) as news_count'))
            ->orderBy('news_count', 'desc')
            ->get()
            ->map(function ($newsItem) {
                $newsCategory = NewsCategory::findOrFail($newsItem->news_category_id);
                $newsItem->news_category_name = $newsCategory->name;
                $newsItem->news_category_color = $newsCategory->color;
                return $newsItem;
            });

    }

    // Method to retrieve news category content
    public function getFetchedNewsCategoryContent($newsCategoryId): bool
    {
         $this->fetchedNewsCategoryContent = ' getFetchedNewsCategoryContent::' . $newsCategoryId;
         \Log::info(varDump($this->fetchedNewsCategoryContent, ' -1 getFetchedNewsCategoryContent $this->fetchedNewsCategoryContent::'));
         \Log::info(varDump($this->newsGroupedByNewsCategoryList, ' -1 getFetchedNewsCategoryContent $this->newsGroupedByNewsCategoryList::'));
        return true;
    }
    // CHECKING LOGS IN METHOD ABOVE I SEE THAT $newsGroupedByNewsCategoryList is empty !!!

    public function render(): View
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.dashboard')->layout('components.layouts.admin');
    }


    // THIS METHOD IS NOT TRIGGERED
    public function updated($property, $value)
    {
        var_dump($property);
        dd($value);
    }

In resources/views/livewire/admin/dashboard.blade.php :
<div class="grid gap-12 lg:grid-cols-2">
    @foreach($newsGroupedByNewsCategoryList as $groupedNewsCategory)
        <div class="flex border-{{ $groupedNewsCategory['news_category_color'] }} border-2 rounded-xl m-1 p-1">

            <div>
                 <p class="mb-2 font-semibold" >{{ $groupedNewsCategory['news_category_name'] }}</p>
                 <div class="admin_main_color ">



                 <div class="flex max-h-9 d1">
                     <div class="flex flex-grow pl-2">
                         {{ $groupedNewsCategory['news_count'] }} news
                     </div>

                     <div class="w-16  align-items-end justify-end align-top m-0 p-1 d2">
                        <span class="d1">
                            <button wire:click="getFetchedNewsCategoryContent({{ $groupedNewsCategory['news_category_id'] }})">
                            </button>
                        </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
   
                      {{ $fetchedNewsCategoryContent }}    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

I load data from mount method and do not understand why calling getFetchedNewsCategoryContent method array newsGroupedByNewsCategoryList becomes empty ?

Using dump($this->fetchedNewsCategoryContent, $this->newsGroupedByNewsCategoryList); insted of Log::info..... ererything works as expected for me (I can see the array content). In your code updated() is never called because you are not updating anything in the view
